# What environment variables/shell variables do env and printenv show

Tags: environment-variables

I have seen related questions such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399964/what-environment-variables-does-printenv-not-list) but they don't provide the exact answer to my question

From my experiments as well as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123473/what-is-the-difference-between-env-and-printenv), `printenv` and `env` pretty much show the same set of system variables.

If I set the variables in

1. /etc/bash.bashrc (supposed to be for system-wide system variables)

   ```
   SYSTEM_ENVI=1000
   ```
2. ~/.bashrc (supposed to be for user-specific system variables)

   ```
   USER_ENVI=10
   ```

I even logged out and logged in so the /etc/environment takes effect.
The following scenario takes place:

```
$echo $SYSTEM_ENVI
//outputs 1000
$echo $USER_ENVI
//outputs 10
$CURR_ENVI=1
$env | grep USER_ENVI
//nothing shows up, the same if I grepped SYSTEM_ENVI or CURR_ENVI
$set | grep USER_ENVI
//shows up USER_ENVI assignment, the same if I grepped SYSTEM_ENVI or CURR_ENVI
```

My questions are:

1. What system variables do `printenv`/`env` print?
2. Should one use `set` to see all accessible variable (system variable and local variable) instead of `printenv` or `env`?

**Regarding not duplication justification**

As far as I am concern, this question and the marked answer helped me realize the facts that:

1. Shell variables are not environment variables
2. Assignments in */etc/bash.bashrc* or *~/.bashrc* don't create environment variables but rather instruct the interactive non-login-shell processes to create and initialize these *shell variables* on startups.

I think my question is not necessarily different from [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/if-processes-inherit-the-parents-environment-why-do-we-need-export) but reading the marked answer on that one doesn't satisfy me as much as the answer given in this post.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/130985/117549

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91282/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller It became clear now thanks to your first link that `env` only shows inherited environment variables. It also sheds lights on the difference `shell variable` and `environment variable`. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`env` and `printenv` are printing the list of environment strings (meant to contain environment variable definitions) that is given to them by the command that executes them. The caller will eventually do a:

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", argv, envp);
```

system call where `argv` and `envp` are two lists of strings.

`env`/`printenv` just print the list of strings in `envp`, one per line.

By convention, the strings in `envp` are in the format `var=value`, but they don't have to be (I don't know of any `execve()` implementation that enforces it) and most `env`, `printenv` implementations don't care when they display them.

When the caller is a POSIX shell, it will include in the `envp` that it passes to `env` the list of its shell variables that are marked for *export* (either because the user called `export`/`typeset -x` on it, or because the variable was already in the environment that the shell received on start-up).

If some of the environment variables that the shell received on start-up could not be mapped to a shell variable, or if any of the `envp` strings it received didn't contain a `=` character, depending on the shell implementation, those strings will be passed along untouched, or the shell will strip them or some of them.

Example with `bash`, using GNU `env` to pass a list of arbitrary variable names (`env` can't pass arbitrary envp strings though, they have to contain a `=`, and the ones that use `setenv()` can't pass some that start with `=`¹).

```
$ env -i '=foo' '1=x' '+=y' bash -c printenv
+=y
1=x
[...]
```

(the variable with the empty name was removed but not the other ones).

Also, if the shell received multiple `envp` strings for the same variable name, depending on the shell, they will all be passed along, or only the first one, or only the last one.

`set` in POSIX shells prints the list of shell variables, including non-scalar ones for shells that support array/hash types, whether they've been marked for export or not.

In POSIX shells you can also use `export -p` to list the variables that have been marked for export. Contrary to `env`/`printenv`, that also lists variables that have been marked for export but not be given any value yet.

In Korn-like shells like `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash`, you can also use `typeset` to get more information including attributes of variables, and list variables by  type (like `typeset -a` to list the array variables).

Here, by adding `USER_ENVI=10` to your `~/.bashrc`, you're configuring the interactive non-login invocations of the `bash` shell to define a `USER_ENVI` *shell* variable on start-up. Since you've not used `export`, that  variable stays a shell variable (unless it was in the environment when `bash` started), so it's not passed as *environment* variables to commands executed by that shell.

`/etc/environment`, itself, on Ubuntu 16.04 is read by the `pam_env.so` pluggable authentication module. Applications that log you in like `login`, `sshd`, `lightdm` will read those files if configured to use `pam_env.so` in `/etc/pam.d` and pass the corresponding *environment* variables (nothing to do with shell variables here) to the command they start in your name after you authenticate (like your login shell for `login`/`sshd`, or your graphical session manager for `lightdm`...).

Since the environment is inherited by default, when your session manager executes a terminal emulator which in turn executes your login shell, those environment variables will be passed along at each step, and your shell will map them to shell variables which you can expand in command line with things like `echo "$VAR"`.

`pam_env` env files like `/etc/environment` look like shell scripts, but `pam_env` doesn't invoke a shell to parse them and understands only a subset of the shell syntax and only allows defining variables whose name is made of one or more ASCII alpha-numeric characters or underscores (it does let you define a `123` variable though which is not a valid POSIX shell variable name).

---

<sup>¹, to pass a list of arbitrary env strings, you can also call `execve()` directly like with:</sup>

```
perl -e 'require "syscall.ph";
         $cmd = "/bin/zsh";
         $args = pack("p*x[p]", "sh", "-c", "printenv");
         $env = pack("p*x[p]", "a=b", "a=c", "", "+=+", "=foo", "bar");
         syscall(SYS_execve(), $cmd, $args, $env)'
```

<sup>here testing with `zsh` instead of `bash`</sup>

Comment: FreeBSD and OpenBSD `env`s both reject `=foo`, because the underlying `setenv()` library call does.

Comment: @JdeBP, here we're not calling `setenv()` but calling `execve()` directly. See also [Protected environment variables?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/137487) and [When do environment strings not have "name=value" form?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/438100)

Comment: Not on FreeBSD and OpenBSD you are not.  The `env` commands call `setenv()` and `execvp()`.

Comment: @JdeBP, but here, I'm talking of passing a `"=foo"` string in the envp in execve(), and `printenv`/`env` will happilly show it. I'm not talking of `setenv()`.

Comment: No, you're talking about running `env`.  It's what the question asks, and it's what you give in the answer, complete with an invocation of `env` with `=foo`.  But your description of what goes on in that invocation, and indeed the output of the command that you show, are not universally true.

Comment: @JdeBP, OK I'm with you now. Yes, that example is to show what a particular shell does with env vars it can't map to variables. The `env` there is just the tool we used to pass that list. If your `env` implementation uses `setenv()` (which POSIX requires it rejects empty env vars, that's not just BSDs), you can use another method to pass that list of env strings, that's not the point I was making here, nor what the question is about. It's about what `env`/`printenv` *print*, not how they can be used to *set* / *pass* env vars. I hope the the edit addresses your objection.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for your answer. The fact you pointed out, which was 'an assignment in ~/.bashrc doesn't make that variable an environment variable that would be passed into command executed by that shell process but rather instructs the interactive non-login shell to create and initialize that variable on startup' helps me a lot in confirming my understandings. I would have up voted all the answers in here if I could, however, due to my low reputation I could not.

Comment: Also, can I have follow up questions on this, please? 1/ Does creating assignments in /etc/bashrc work the same (instructs shell to initialize variables on startups, not environment variable) 2/ How about setting an assignment in /etc/environment, does it create environment variable or initialize shell variables on startups?

Comment: @TranTriet 1/ yes, bash does read `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` depending on how it was built on startup when interactive and non-login. See `info -n 'Bash Startup Files' bash` for details. 2/  see edit.

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
USER_ENVI=10
```

You are setting a variable, but not an environment variable. For that you need:

```
export USER_ENVI=10
```

Or

```
USER_ENVI=10; export USER_ENVI
```

It is reasonable that this doesn't work for you:

```
$ env | grep SYSTEM_ENVI
```

There is no environment variable called `SYSTEM_ENVI` set. There is nothing about `/etc/environment` that we can say as you have not posted its contents (nor seem to be using it).

What `env` will print is exactly the same that `printenv` should print (without options).

Answers:

1. Both env and printenv will report exactly the same list of variables actually set **iif** there are no options or variable list after the command.
2. You could use set (without options) to see all variables set. That doesn't mean that you **must** use it. It depends on what you do want to list. It is perfectly valid and correct to list only the list of environment variables.

Comment: You've missed the fact that the question's assumption about `/etc/environment` is wrong.  One several operating systems that's just a meaningless file in `/etc` that nothing uses.  On those operating systems that _do_ use it, it is important to know what reads it, and realize that it might be turned off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not mention in my post that an exported variable would show up in `env`'s output. I know that it does. Now I understand that because `export` makes that shell variable an **environment-variable** and since `env` only prints the environment variables, that is the expected output. Again, I would have up voted your answer if I could but I can't due to my low reputation. Also, thanks for answering both questions!

Comment: Since the above answer really gives me what I was looking for (e.g. 'creating an assignment in ~/.bashrc doesn't create an environment variable, but rather instructs the shell to create a shell variable on startup'), I am going to mark that answer as the official answer. But I want to thank you once again for your help!

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, your comment made me re-edit the answer but because `/etc/environment` wasn't used. It seems that you missed that fact.

Comment: @TranTriet I am happy that this answer has helped you. That is all that is needed.